# ¿error pasar valores sin signo a una función?

Tags: c++, c, funciones

tengo la siguiente función pero me aparece error al querer mandar variables sin signo o `unsigned`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void Get_values(char linea[],int32_t unsigned& valor1,int32_t unsigned& valor2,char country[]){

 char numero[100];
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;

    while(linea[i] != ','){

    numero[j++] = linea[i++];

   }

  numero[j] = '\0';
  valor1 = atoi(numero); 
  j = 0;
  i++;

  while(linea[i] != ','){

    numero[j++] = linea[i++];

   }
  numero[j] = '\0';
  valor2 = atoi(numero); 
  j = 0;
  i++;
  while(linea[i] != ','){
    country[j++] = linea[i++];   
   }    
 }
```

y estos son los valores que quiero enviar

```
char linea[100];
 char country[3]; 
 int unsigned  numero1 = 0;
 int unsigned  numero2 = 0;

Get_values(linea,numero1,numero2,country);
```

[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]

[image: compilacion1]

Comment: Cosas como `const` son calificadores. Estos no crean tipos nuevos, solo agregan propiedades a tipos existentes. `unsigned` no es un calificador, algo como `unsigned int` es un tipo completamente diferente a `int`. Al no ser un calificador, no puedes agregarlo porque si como lo agregas en `int32_t unsigned& valor1`. O usas `unsigned int` como tus variables, o puedes usar `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Pablochaches el problema es que me esta votando valores negativos en mi programa,edite la pregunta para que mires